# Interface for hierarchy of objects only partially needed on the lowest class

Tags: java, oop, subclass

I have 4 different classes all which extend from an abstract class which in turn implements an interface.

Class #1 contains an array of Class #2 objects.
Class #2 contains an array of Class #3 objects.
Class #3 contains an array of Class #4 objects.
Class #4 contains no array.

The getters for these arrays all come from the interface on their parent class.
Currently I have the getter in Class #4 just returning null and the JavaDoc explaining that it's the lowest in the hierarchy of objects and therefore cannot have anything to get.

Class #4 does need to implement the interface as it has other methods which all levels of the hierarchy need.

Is this acceptable practice?

Edit: Should the getter be in it's own specific interface which is directly implemented by Classes #1/#2/#3?

Comment: getters and setters on interfaces make no sense to me, I would get rid of this hierarchy altogether.

Comment: Why do you need to have a class hierarchy? Does composition better solve your problem?

Comment: p.s. Code speaks louder than words. See [mcve] for tips on creating a good code example.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi - sorry I wasn't clear, the getter only returns a specific object from the array, as in `getChild(string ID)`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice They're all subjects in an observer pattern which also is implemented via the interface plus a couple of other small bits.

Comment: It sounds like you need to rethink the inheritance hierarchy. Perhaps the interface can be broken into two or more interfaces. Then classes can mix and match those interfaces as they wish.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - something like this? https://puu.sh/yPxhA/743318de8c.png

Comment: Yes, that is similar to what I had in mind.